# mod_rewrite static URL to dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite this URL

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/number/50.html
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/number?id=50#50
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/number/([^/]+)\.html/?  /folder/number?id=$1#$1  [NE,NC,L]
```

Map silently

`http://www.domain.com/folder/number/50.html`  with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://www.domain.com/folder/number?id=50#50`

String `50` is assumed to be dynamic.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [NE,NC,L] with [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Comment: Thank you, but folder & number aren't dynamic.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference and it's always better to give that information in the question. What else is missing?

Comment: Made some simple changed onto your code and figured it out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to do it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/number/(\d+)\.html$ folder/number?id=$1#$1 [L,R=301]
```

Change `[L,R=301]` to `[L]` if you want this redirection to be transparent.